# How to read lines of numbers from txt file

Tags: c++

So in my txt file I have numbers like this

```
1,200,400
2,123,321
3,450,450
4,500,250
```

each time I will have 3 numbers, and I need to read them and save them in some variables, can anyone help me out on how to do this, since mostly I get on tutorials showing how to read characters but if I try to write them in variables I get some weird numbers...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::fstream myfile("filename.txt", std::ios_base::in);

int a ,b,c;
char ch; //For skipping commas
while (myfile>> a >> ch >> b>> ch >>c)
{
    // Play with a,b,c
}

myfile.close();
```

Comment: What about the commas in the input?

Comment: I really like this one because of the simplicity , but how can I make it read untill the end of the file , like all rows not just one.

Comment: @user2850409 the `while` loop will read file as long as stream is in good state, i.e. till end of file

Comment: now it works I forgot to do the right "pattern" in while loop ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the numbers, you need to [`.ignore()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) the comma (or extract it into a `char`). If you want to save the tuples you can use a [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of [`std::tuple<int, int, int>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple):

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int,int,int>> myNumbers;
int number1, number2, number3;

while(((file >> number1).ignore() >> number2).ignore() >> number3){
    myNumbers.push_back(make_tuple(number1, number2, number3));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way (I guess) is to read the commas into dummy char variables.

```
int num1, num2, num3;
char comma1, comma2;
while (file >> num1 >> comma1 >> num2 >> comma2 >> num3)
{
    ...
}
```

Having read the commas into the variables `comma1` and `comma2` you can then ignore them since all you're really interested in is the numbers.

Comment: I really like this one , but it only reads 1 line , how can I make it read more then 1 line?

Comment: @user2850409 It should read more than one line, that's why I used a while loop. Perhaps you should ask a new question if you're having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is in the same format as a CSV file so you can use this.

From http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/13087/

```
ifstream file ( "file.csv" );
    string value;
    while ( file.good() )
    {
         getline ( file, value, ',' ); // read a string until next comma: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/
         cout << string( value, 1, value.length()-2 ); // display value removing the first and the last character from it
    }
```

Comment: cplusplus.com is a source of bad habbits and coding styles. This is one example.

Comment: But I dont need to display my value, I need to use it in my code for building my levels, wich makes that 1st and last character kind of a problem.